# Invoking an ActivityAction in a SharePoint workflow

Tags: workflow, 2013, workflow-activity, visual-studio-2012

In a Visual Studio, SharePoint 2013 workflow, the "IF" Activity provided by Microsoft can take a condition and two activities as parameters:
[image]

I want to write a custom activity that can similarly accept other activities as parameters. In other words, delegating other activities.

EDIT:
I've found that if I add a property argument of type "ActivityAction":
[image]

The visual studio designer renders it and allows you to drop other activities into it:
[image]

Now I just need a way to invoke that "Body" property/delegate.

Unfortunately the InvokeDelegate activity does not seem to be supported in a SharePoint workflow:
[image]
Would it be possible to write a Code Activity that replicates this functionality? Or even better, is there another way to call/execute an ActivityAction?

[Here's an MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh305737.aspx) that shows how to do this in a **non-sharepoint** workflow with Workflow Manager 1.0.

Edit:

Still looking on an answer. Any updates with the Workflow Manager 1.0 refresh?

Comment: Can you give us an example of how you would use this?

Comment: @MonkeyWrench An example would be creating a custom activity that does something before executing another activity given to it. Example: Replicating microsoft's "IF" activity, without the compulsory Else. Notice that in microsoft's If activity, the "Then" body is one delegate, the "Else" body is another. I want to find a way to execute these delegates. Which microsoft does, after all- since the activities you place in the "Then" block are executed (albeit conditionally).

Comment: I'm sure this is possible, given that I got this far and that Microsoft does it. Could any SharePoint genius give this a shot? Don't be lazy, you're not going to Google your way out of this one :P

Comment: I will have to wait until I'm on VS2013 as I believe there are some vast improvements to do what you are asking with ease :)

Comment: Wow, 8 months, two bounties. Nothing on Google. Zero answers. Man, I love SharePoint!

Comment: This will not answer your question, just heads up...

The IF activity is a core Workflow Foundation (WF) thing... not a Workflow Manager activity / SharePoint activity. If you are looking to create something similar to that, I'd remove SharePoint from the equation to simplify things.

Addressing the "support" part of your question, SharePoint won't care about it. SharePoint 2013 doesn't do workflow anymore, it outsources it 100% to Workflow Manager. It has no concept of what activities are installed or not in WM.

Comment: @AndrewConnell Yes but certain things like a NativeActivity which you can create in WorkflowManager, you can't use in a SharePoint workflow AFAIK. There are some limitations, right?

Comment: Why couldn't you use it? If you have the activity deployed both to the Workflow Manager farm as well as on your developer machine, it should work. SharePoint doesn't know what's included on the WM farm, just like any app that relies on something being previously deployed to the server. If it didn't work with it, it would be news to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my answer I'll be focusing on the *Activity* I have implemented, I will not cover how to implement custom activities. You can find additional information about development and deployment of custom activities on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj193517(v=azure.10).aspx.

This is the solution I believe you are looking for:

```
[Designer("System.Activities.Core.Presentation.DoWhileDesigner, System.Activities.Core.Presentation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35", "System.ComponentModel.Design.IDesigner")]
public sealed class DelegateActivity : NativeActivity
{
    [DependsOn("Condition"), DefaultValue((string)null)]
    public Activity Body
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    protected override void Execute(NativeActivityContext context)
    {
        context.ScheduleActivity(Body);
    }
}
```

Add pre-executing and post-executing logic in *Execute* method if that's what you need.

Now, one disclaimer... I have used *DoWhileDesigner* value in *Designer* attribute in my implementation since I didn't implement my own *Designer*. You could do that by inheriting from *ActivityDesigner* and implementing *IComponentControl*. You would have to provide your own XAML for the designer.

Simply drop any activity in *DelegateActivity* in Visual Studio and workflow will execute it. This implementation disregards *Condition*, so you can leave it blank:
[image]

Comment: Cool. Need to try this, but is it possible to expose the "Body" as an output parameter for an existing declarative activity and then execute that body?

Comment: @David Could you create a new post with more details on what you're trying to accomplish with output parameter? Please let me know if my answer solves your original issue.

Comment: Made a mistake with the previous comment. If your code activity can accept the "body" parameter passed down from a declerative (non-code) activity and execute it - it solves the problem. I'll try it out and accept if it works :)

Comment: When you say "accept the 'body' parameter", do you mean dragging the activity from Visual Studio toolbox onto DelegateActivity? If yes, then it should work, I've tested it by dragging built-in WriteToHistory activity onto DelegateActivity.

Comment: No. Please try to understand the declarative activity part. The problem is simple: Somebody writes a declarative activity that accepts delegates. And wishes to execute said delegates. Can your code activity be used to execute those delegates, passed down as a parameter from the original declarative activity hosting your code activity? I'm thinking the answer is yes, need to try.